# Python virtualenv has changed sys.path permanently

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have activated a python virtualenv (dev) for one of my projects. However, don't know what happened, it looks like it has changed the path permanently. I cannot access my global packages. When I print sys.path it shows me paths related to virtualenv (dev) which is no more activated. When I run pip list, it shows me packages installed for virtualenv (dev) and not the ones install globally (c:\python27\Lib\sitepackages). Any idea what must have gone wrong? And how do I reset sys.path?

I checked out RegistryKey (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\PythonPath) and Environment variables, everything looks okay. Any light on this issue would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Your default environment variables may be wrong in path, since the default path must point to the python globally.

Try this:

1. Start menu > Run > 'sysdm.cpl' > Enter
2. Search for the tab 'Advanced'
3. Finally 'Environment Variables'

Edit the system variable '*Path*'

**Carefully** and search for the python path, just change it to the global paths instead.

c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQT4 (usually)
c:\python27
c:\python27\scripts

Hope I could help.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, environment variables (including path) looks okay and properly points to c:\python27\* directories... Surprisingly there is no mention of the directory (which was configured in virtualenv) in system path, still it shows in sys.path.

Comment: Have you tried in another cmd window? Or deactivating the virtualenv ?